# Compare given Year with todays date

Tags: javascript

I have a select field with multiple answer possibilities ranging from 2000 to 2050. So if someone chooses 2013, I need the function to give me a variable with the amount of years passed since 2013.

I tried searching for the code but i didn't find any that fit my need. 
Thanks to all of you in advance.

Comment: Have you heard of _subtraction_?  Just take the difference of the two year numbers.

Comment: Of course but how can i subtract dd/mm/yyyy from dd/mm/yyyy?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the javascript date object. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp

```
var date = new Date(); //create date object
var year = date.getFullYear(); //get the year from date object

var enteredYear = parseInt("2000"); //get the value from the select

var diff = year - enteredYear;
/* for absolute value use:
var diff = Math.abs(year - enteredYear);
*/

//do something with it!!
alert('The difference is ' + diff + ' years');
```

**Output**
The difference is 17 years (it is currently 2017)

Good Luck!! Hope this helps you!!